# A term that describes the "shoulder angel/devil" but on a broader scale

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am attempting to find a phrase or word equivalent to "shoulder angel/devil", but on a broader scale, that does not only refer to the idea of "good" versus "bad". The angel/devil concept is when a  character has an imaginary angel on one shoulder and an imaginary devil on the other, both telling the character what to do.

A shoulder angel/devil is a plot device often used for comic or dramatic effect. They are used to depict the inner conflict of character.

[image: (The angel dog says to scratch on the door so the people can let him out to pee, while the devil dog says to just go ahead and pee on the rug)]

One of the key elements in the novel *Jane Eyre* by Charlotte Bronte is *passion* versus *restraint*; as in this sentence:

> Reason sits firm and holds the reins...the passions may rage...but judgement shall still have the last word (page. 282)

As such, passion and restraint are personified, like a shoulder angel/devil, thus I am looking for a term that can be used to explain this technique.

Comment: You could perhaps start by explaining what "shoulder angel/devil" means, or what you understand it to mean.  I have never heard that phrase.

Comment: Sounds like conflicting emotions, drives, or imperatives.

Comment: Are you looking for *right vs wrong* (ethics / morality) or *thought vs desire* (decision-making)?

Comment: Diametric voices or forces? Dueling voices or forces?

Comment: Why is the good guy telling him to scratch on the door? *Bad dog!*

Comment: Stress: the confusion you feel when your mind overrides your body's desire to strangle someone who desperately deserves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dualistic voices that command me. One asks me to do ill the other good.

Answer (score 1):

This common visual trope depicts the *[conscience](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/conscience)*:

> An inner feeling or voice viewed as acting as a guide to the rightness
>   or wrongness of one’s behavior.

Comment: See also,  [Jiminy Cricket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiminy_Cricket).

Answer (score 0):

If you are of a biblical frame of mind, you might co-opt the apostle Paul's verbiage when he talks of "the spirit versus the flesh" and "the flesh versus the spirit," as in his letter to the Romans, Chapter 8.

You needn't be "religious," however, to appreciative the timelessness of the two concepts of "flesh" and "spirit."

To this day, we talk about "the pleasures of the flesh," or "fleshly appetites," or "carnal delights" which many people, I suppose, associate primarily with sexual libertinism and promiscuity).

On the other hand, when moderns talk about spiritual desires, they are likely referring either to traditional religious practices and perspectives or to the pleasures available via cogitation, the acquisition of knowledge, meditation, prayer, or via any number of other practices which are more cerebral and ideational than fleshly and carnal.

One--but certainly not the only--school of thought in this regard is *Manichaeism*, which is [comprised of](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Manicheanism) the doctrines and practices of the dualistic religious system of *Manes*, a blending of Gnostic Christianity, Buddhism, Zoroastrianism, and other elements, especially doctrines of a cosmic conflict between forces of light and darkness, the darkness and evilness of matter, and the necessity for . . .sexual . . . asceticism.

The notion of self-mortification has been with us in both the East and the West for millennia. At its heart, I suggest, is the belief that the physical body and its appetites are bad and need to be stifled, whereas the higher aspirations of the spirit and soul--the immaterial components of human life--are
good and need to be nourished.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for a diametrically opposed decision tree. This was thoroughly worked out by Sigmeund Freud in *The Ego and the Id*. The **ego** is the head in your cartoon, the id is the devil, and the superego is the heavenly creatu,e.

Essentially, the brain is driven by forces; what we as people do with those forces is the psychological construct known as *Drive Theory*. The id directs our behavior towards hedonism, wanton procreation, and chaos. The opposing psychological scheme is the superego: our sense of morality. It may have been inherited, taught, or infused into our soul; or if one is a psychopath--absent.

The **ego** is where our conscious thoughts live, and we as humans have free will and choice. However, state of mind has a profound effect on where the ego goes with its decision making.

As an aside, this is a separate psychological construct from Freud's work on the *conscious, preconscious, and unconscious*.